# Switching from APC to APCu

Tags: php, caching, apc

I am running a web server with Debian and I'm hosting a ZF1 project. 
The PHP process crashes from time to time without any reason, so my hosting provider suggests that I should switch from APC to APCu caching. I'm not very familiar with PHP caching and I can't really find any documentation on the topic, but I read a few similar questions here.

As far as I understand the APCu caches only user data (whatever that means) and it's not the full features of the APC. Considering this, my question is will APCu increase the load of the server and will the PHP extension work out of the box without touching the ZF1 code?

Answer (score 1):

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Does-ZF-1-12-support-PHP-5-5-td4661902.html

You should upgrade to the latest PHP on a test environment, if it works well (most likely scenario), you can switch. PHP 5.5 has built-in opcode cache (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php), so you won't lose performance. Very little difference can be between the performance of APCu and APC.

Also, function names are not identical (apcu_fetch for instance), so you have to modify the code to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried upgrading to 5.5, but the code throws a lot of warnings and notices, so I'm sticking with 5.4. APC functions are used in the code in a lot of places, but I saw that APCu emulated them so it works fine for now. For anyone else who has the same issue: APCu works great without any code changes, because like I said it emulates APC and you can just swap it for 2 minutes.